# How draw a state diagram with actors

Tags: uml

Im new in UML,

I am recently in charge of a web application, this application manages projects through a flow of states. There are multiple users within the application and each of them can intervene in the flow in a certain state.

Therefore I want to represent this information through a state diagram for me and for future developers do not have to ask the same question again.

My question is: How do I represent the different actors in the state diagram and their intervention in each of them?

- Do I need to create a different state diagram for each actor?
- Is there a diagram to do this that you do not know?

Thanks.

This is my example diagram and how an actor can pass from stateX to stateY

[image]

Comment: Why would you document the actor's states? Drinking coffee, hungry, tired. That should do xD

Comment: Because its easy for me to knows when a specific actor can go from stateX to stateY. In the application are +20 different roles and 20+ different project states. It's hard to remember this.

Comment: You didn't get my point. Actor's states are not really relevant. It's the system's states which are.

Comment: Oh, im sorry. Maybe I expressed myself wrong. (My poor english ...) I dont need a diagram of Actor's states, the diagram is of system's states.

Comment: Ok, but what are the actor's roles here? You should give a concrete example here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to oversimplify your model.

Each actor has certain system functionality that they can run. These single functionalities are called Use Cases (UC) and you present them on a Use Case diagram. This diagram shows which Actor can perform what Use Case but it does not show a relation to a state. While each Use Case can have pre-conditions defining what has to be true before the UC can be performed and post-conditions declaring what will be true if the UC ends successfully (which in your case would both probably be something like "System is in State A"), UC diagram does not support showing pre- and post-conditions. You can always add them in the notes attached to a UC.

To have a clear view of the system State Machine you can use two diagrams. One will be UC diagram, the other one will be State Machine Diagram or to be more specific Protocol State Machine. Then on State Machine you depict which UC causes what system State change while UC diagram provides information which Actor is eligible for running specific UC.

Finally you can use Sequence Diagram if you want to model how specific flow of interactions in the system impact changes of the system state. You can present states and actors on a single diagram here, but it is not designed, cannot and should not be used to depict all possibilities on a single diagram.

**Disclaimer**
Next part of my answer is opinion based
**/Disclaimer**

Most probably I would use UC diagram and SM diagram together according to information you've provided.

---

### On the notation

A side note to your diagram - ovals are used only on UC diagram and represent Use Cases. They are not associated with each other, only with Actors.
States are presented as rectangles with rounded corners (both in State Machine Diagram and Sequence Diagram).

Comment: Any combination of diagrams is allowed by UMl standard. The combined use of UC and SM diagrams is allowed one more. So, your opinion is absolutely up to the opinion of the UML creators. :-)

Comment: @Gangnus of course. I am saying what I would do in this scenario, based on my UML knowledge and experience. I've been dealing with UML models for over 15 years now, passed all 3 level of UML certification (though it has already expired), working professionally as a BA and teaching others about UML usage. However, there is no such thing as "the only good solution" here. That's why I still consider this part of my answer as being opinion based.